# How to use binding for IsReadOnly property of a DateTimeField?

Tags: wpf, xaml, infragistics

I have XamDataGrid with couple of DateTimeFields, Now I have to bind IsReadOnly property of the column to a property of DataItem.
How can I achieve this using ValueConverters?

Comment: Could you include a code sample?

Comment: bit tough to include sample, anyaway I noticed that IsReadOnly column of DateTimeField can not be bound with any property, it is bug of @infragistics I guess.